# Careers 2.0 plain-text Markdown exports would be useful

Tags: feature-request, jobs

On some sites (e.g. jobvite.com) having a plain-text resume is necessary. It would be helpful if there was a way to export Careers 2.0 resumes to a human readable plain-text format such as Markdown.